# Onchange AJAX for textarea not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, safari

I have an AJAX function that works just fine when I'm on my PC. But when I switch to Safari (mobile), only the radio-boxes will trigger the AJAX. How come?

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="q1r1" name="q1" value="Awesome" onchange="GrabData(this)">
<input type="radio" id="q1r3" name="q1" value="Awful" onchange="GrabData(this)">

<div class="comment"><textarea name='q1comment' id='comment' maxlength="400" placeholder="Add a comment (max 400 characters)" onchange="GrabC(this)"></textarea>
```

AJAX

```
//AJAX question 1.
        function GrabData(Passeddata){
            var radioValue = Passeddata.value;
            var URL = "question1.php?q1=" + radioValue + "&teamid=" + <?php echo $teamid; ?>; 
            $.ajax( {
                url : URL,
                type : "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data == "") {
                        alert("data is empty");
                    } else {
                        console.log('got your data back sir');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
//AJAX for comment question 1.
        function GrabC(PassedComment){
            var radioValue = PassedComment.value;
            var URL = "question1.php?comment1=" + radioValue + "&teamid=" + <?php echo $teamid; ?>; 
            $.ajax( {
                url : URL,
                type : "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    if (data == "") {
                        alert("data is empty");
                    } else {
                        console.log('got your data back sir');
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Again, works fine on my PC, the textarea onchange does not seems to work on Safari on the mobile. Can't figure out why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `keyup` event along with `change`; `change` triggers when you blur, focus (not sure of this) on the element, but `keyup` actually listens for changes while the user is typing/tapping the keys.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('change keyup', function(){
    $('#console').text($('#console').text()+ "\r\n"+ this.value);
});
$('textarea').on('change keyup', function(){
    $('#console').text($('#console').text()+ "\r\n"+ this.value);
    /** Send to AJAX 
       GrabC(this);
       GrabData(this);
    **/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<textarea row="4"></textarea>
<pre id="console"></pre>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.. Just gotta figure out how to apply it to my code then :/

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to trigger an actual AJAX function with it?

Comment: I can remove the `$('#console').text($('#console').text()+ "\r\n"+ this.value);` part, right? And assign `$('textarea').on('change keyup', function(){` to an id like: `$('#q1comment')` right? Trying to eliminate errors before I mess this stuff up

Comment: You remove the console-related stuff, that's right. And for the id, make sure it exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100095/discussion-between-john-smith-and-adam-azad).